# make textbox work like dropdown box

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to replicate the functionality I have on a dropdown box that allows a user to select a tag and then return articles related to this term,.

The textbox needs to accept a search term and work in the same way. I have tried everything I can think of but I am getting zero results.

To replicate the behavior, select an item from the dropdown box and it will return articles. Then try typing the same term in the search box and it returns no articles.

Any idea why? Here's the site:

http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/getpocket/view.html

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of the `validateForm` function

Comment: We need to see some code. Can you post some? It seems that the textbox is passing the variable correctly, but what happens from there?

Comment: @PitaJ is right. Your code can't stop the submit action so the page will be refreshed, that's why there is no search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to change your search box code to something like this:

```
<form name="searchform" >
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
    <input type="button" value="search" onclick="validateForm()">
</form>
```

Since you are not really submitting a form and don't want to reload a page, you can just use the `click` event from a `button` rather than the `submit` event from the `form`.

If you want to have it get the article when hitting  the `Enter` button, here is one way to do it (there might be better ways I am just not thinking of now...). You can use the `keydown` event to run a function that will test for the `Enter` button. When it finds it, it will call `validateForm`. Add this function to your script:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("searchterm").addEventListener(
       "keydown", keydown
    );
    function keydown(e){

       if(e.keyIdentifier == "Enter"){
          validateForm();
       }
    }
}
```

and change your body tag to this:

```
<body onload="init();">
```

That attach the `keydown` event listener to the `textbox` once the page has loaded.

One note of warning: I am testing this on a Linux laptop running Chrome. I don't know if Mac  calls the `Enter` key `Return` and I don't know if `.keyIdentifier` is cross-browser compatible. That is something you need to look into, but this should get you started.

Comment: is it possible to make the text box work by pressing return after a value has been entered as well as press the searching button?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery UI combobox. It allowes you to type values, autocomplete and with a dropdown functionality. It takes some time to get comfortable with jQuery UI but its robust and fits almost every solution regarding user interaction:

[jQuery UI Combobox demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)